# How should we return direct soql query results from apex method to batch job?

Tags: apex, batch

How to return soql results to the batch job?

Apex Method:

```
            public PageReference process(){ 
                if(checkBoxVal==true){
                    VoucherGenerate_AssignBatch b = new VoucherGenerate_AssignBatch();
                    Database.executeBatch(b);               
                    flag = true;  
                    flag1 = false ; 

                    String query = 'SELECT Id,Login__c,Name,Priority__c,Opportunity__c,Opportunity__r.CloseDate, Attandance_Status__c,  WebinarContact__c,WebinarContact__r.Name,WebinarContact__r.Email,'+
                        'Voucher_Number__c,Email_Sent__c  FROM Webinar_Attendees__c WHERE Opportunity__c != Null  AND Attandance_Status__c = \'Attended\' '; 
                    system.debug('query :: '+query);
                    return Database.getQueryLocator(query); 
                    Myresult = Database.query(query);

                }
            }
```

Batch Job:

```
global with sharing class VoucherGenerate_AssignBatch implements Database.Batchable<SObject>, Database.Stateful {
    global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext bc) {
    }
    global void execute (Database.BatchableContext bc, List<Webinar_Attendees__c> scope) {}
    global void finish(Database.BatchableContext batchableContext) {} 
}
```

Comment: Do not ever use `global` access modifier unless you are writing a web service endpoint.

Comment: From what you've posted, it's not clear what the relationship is between the Apex method and the Batch class. Your Apex `public PageReference process()` method isn't going to compile, because it's trying to return a QueryLocator instead of a PageReference. Please edit your question to clarify what you want to do, and why that static query can't be in the `start()` method of your Batch class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Controller**

```
public void process() {
   String query = 'Select ...';
   Database.executeBatch(new VoucherGenerate_AssignBatch(query));
}
```

Batchable

```
public with sharing class VoucherGenerate_AssignBatch implements Database.Batchable<SObject>, Database.Stateful {

    String query;
    public Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext bc) {
       return Database.getQueryLocator(this.query);
    }
    public void execute (Database.BatchableContext bc, List<Webinar_Attendees__c> scope) {}
    public void finish(Database.BatchableContext batchableContext) {} 

    // constructor
    public VoucherGenerate_AssignBatch(String query) {this.query=query;}
}
```